# How to order cumulated payments in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails app I have the following models:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :payments

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :person

end
```

---

How can I get the `payments` for each `person` and order them by **sum**?

This is my controller:

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @people = current_account.people.includes(:payments).where(:payments => { :date => @range }).order("payments.amount DESC")
  end

end
```

It gives me the correct numbers but the order is wrong. I want it to start with the `person` having the highest sum of payments within a `range`.

This is the current `Payments` table:

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: You cannot use aggregated field in the query that does not have `GROUP BY` clause, grouping by that field. Either you have to return `SUM` back and then ordering will be available, or you have to do two queries against the database. Think SQL, rails sucks.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin tells us how you really feel :) but anyway you can do this using a subquery as a join (even in rails if you are good with a bit of Arel code)

Comment: @engineersmnky `arel` is great, yes.

Comment: @engineersmnky: No, I'm not good at Rails or Arel at all.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin yes it is. It is a shame that `rails` consumed it into core but it wasn't all that useful without an `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapter` anyway so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
payments = Payment.arel_table
sum_payments = Arel::Table.new('sum_payments')
payments_total = payments.join(
     payments.project(
       payments[:person_id],
       payments[:amount].sum.as('total')
     )
     .where(payments[:date].between(@range))
     .group( payments[:person_id])
     .as('sum_payments'))
     .on(sum_payments[:person_id].eq(Person.arel_table[:id]))
```

This will create broken SQL (selects nothing from payments which is syntactically incorrect and joins to people which does not even exist in this query) but we really only need the join e.g.

```
 payments_total.join_sources.first.to_sql
 #=> INNER JOIN (SELECT payments.person_id, 
 #     SUM(payments.amount) AS total 
 #      FROM payments 
 #      WHERE 
 #        payments.date BETWEEN ... AND ...
 #       GROUP BY payments.person_id) sum_payments 
 #      ON sum_payments.id = people.id
```

So knowing this we can pass the `join_sources` to [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#joins`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins) and let `rails` and `arel` handle the rest like so

```
current_account
 .people
 .includes(:payments)
 .joins(payments_total.join_sources) 
 .where(:payments => { :date => @range })
 .order("sum_payments.total DESC")
```

Which should result in SQL akin to

```
SELECT 
 -- ...
FROM 
  people
  INNER JOIN payments ON payments.person_id = people.id 
  INNER JOIN ( SELECT payments.person_id,
                 SUM(payments.amount) as total
               FROM payments
               WHERE 
                  payments.date BETWEEN -- ... AND ...
               GROUP BY payments.person_id) sum_payments ON 
     sum_payments.person_id = people.id
WHERE
   payments.date BETWEEN -- ... AND ..
ORDER BY 
   sum_payments.total DESC
```

This will show all the people having made payments in a given date range (along with those payments) sorted by the sum of those payments in descending order.

This is untested as I did not bother to set up a whole rails application but it should be functional.